# In multiplicative subgroup Fp* of an elliptic curve does multiplying an element make it leave the subgroup?

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field

In the case of an Elliptic curve over a GF(p) which has order n and multiplicative group of n-1 elements, does multiplication of an element of a subgroup of order q where q is a divisor of n-1 with a scalar s obey the cyclic property, or plainly put does an element e member of subgroup q when multiplied with s stay in the subgroup?

Ok an update and the clarification, my colleague has put forth the claim that given the Nist256r1 curve, which has a prime number of elements (points), the number of valid integers/scalars that equals order n-1 can be factored into smaller subgroups, and if an element of that subgroup was used as the private key, part of a DH key, any subsequent multiplication of the resulting EC point would still remain in the subgroup bounded by the choice of private key.
To me this sounds like mixing different groups but as I explained not a maths guy.
So to restate the question: Is what he is claiming reasonable since that would constitute changing of the order of the calculated EC point.

Comment: If an ECC has order $n$ then the order of the subgroups must divide $n$. Also, the standard terminology is point addition. Your question, as of currently, is not clear.

Comment: If you are asking, let $n$ be the order of the ECC group where $q$ is a divisor of the order, and let $e \in <P>$ where $P$ is a subgroup with order $q$ ( existance is not guaranteed) the adding $e$ itself $k$ times $[k]e \in <P>$

Comment: "an Elliptic curve over a GF(p) which has order n and multiplicative grouo on n-1 elements"; I have problems parsing this.  When we talk about $\mathbb{Z}/p$, there are addition and multiplication operations defined, and we can define a group ($\mathbb{Z}_p^*$) which has (if $p$ is prime) $p-1$ elements (this happens because there is one element of $\mathbb{Z}/p$, namely 0, which is not a member of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$).  Nothing similar happens with elliptic curves; there is only one operation (elliptic curve addition), and so we don't use up with a group with $n-1$ elements.

Comment: On the other hand, to answer the question in the title "does multiplying a subgroup element (by an integer) make it leave the subgrouop", no it doesn't.  Subgroups are closed; that is, if $A$, and $B$ are members of the subgroup, so is $A+B$.  Hence, $nA = A + A + ... + A$ is also in the subgroup.

Comment: Thank you for the answers kelalaka and poncho, I will try to clarify the question. I was refering to the claim in the answer to this question https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/114570/is-there-a-subgroup-of-order-2n-for-large-n-of-the-prime-field-that-secp256k1

Comment: I got involved in a discussion about subgroups and my intuition tells me that if an element would be trapped in the subgroup that would make DiffieHellman keys trivial to compromise, so i believe that the other party is confusing the multiplicative subgroup with the group of points defined by the curve.

Comment: @immigrantswede: if the order of the subgroup is large (e.g. $> 2^{256}$), why would the fact that $sE$ (where $E$ is an element of the subgroup) is also in the subgroup lead to a vulnerability?

Comment: @immigrantswede it is prime order curve. There is no subgroups other than the trivials

Comment: @poncho in that case it would not lead to a vulnerability, on the contrary if the order of the subgroup was sufficiently small it would allow for a trivial small subgroup confinement attack, now the point i was trying to clarify as a non mathematician was that even if the order of the Fp* group was factorable and had factors of a computable size lets say smaller than 2^60 that does not imply that an element from that subgroup compromises the security of the curve. Since as kelalaka pointed out a prime order curve does not have a group other than the trivials

Comment: [It is called small subgroup attack](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/twist.html), the cofactor as in Curve25519 can leak 3-bits, prime curves none. There is also twist security where the small subgroups can play an important role...

Comment: The elliptic curve group is an additive group & the likewise the subgroup - multiplication by a scalar is actually addition. With generator $G$ & scalar $n$, $n\cdot G$ is actually addition - $G + G + G + G ....$ $n$ times. Since addition of 2 subgroup elements always remains in the subgroup, multiplication by a scalar remains in the subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ok an update and the clarification, my colleague has put forth the claim that given the Nist256r1 curve, which has a prime number of elements (points), the number of valid integers/scalars that equals order n-1 can be factored into smaller subgroups

Your colleague is wrong.  As mentioned in the comments, the size of any subgroup is always a divisor of the size of the full group.  Nist256r1 (Secp256r1) has a prime number of points, and since the only divisors of a prime is the prime itself and one, the only subgroups that exist are the full curve (with $n$ points) and the subgroup that consists only of the point-at-infinity (with 1 point).  There are no other possibilities.

I believe that your colleague is getting confused between $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, which does have $p-1$ elements (assuming $p$ is prime), and so always (for $p>3$) has proper subgroups, and elliptic curves, which has $n$ elements (for some $n$ close to $p$ for prime curves, but need not be $p-1$).  To oversimplify, the elliptic curve replaces the $p-1$ by $n$, and hence you don't need to subtract one again.

> Is what he is claiming reasonable since that would constitute changing of the order of the calculated EC point.

No, it is not reasonable; for the Secp256r1 curve, all points (except for the point at infinity) have order $n$.  And, if $P$ is not the point at infinity, then $aP$ can be any point on the curve (with the appropriate value for $a$).

Comment: Thank you Poncho this ahould settle the discussion

Comment: The linked Q is about bitcoin which uses secp256k1 not secp256r1=(X9)prime256v1=(NIST)P-256. But _all_ SECG-and-X9 $F_p$ curves have prime order so the reasoning still applies.